# Does the movement speed obtained from different sources add up in dnd5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, flight

For example, will a character with wings gain an additional 30 feet of flight speed if he wears Winged boots? I have recently studied the topic of speed and flight in dnd a lot, but so far I have not heard that the speeds obtained from different sources do not add up. And I would not have asked this question if one player had not told me about it.

Comment: May I recommend that you start your studies by looking at the relevant sections of the player's handbook? This rule is literally on the first page of the "[Movement and Position](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#FlyingMovement)" rules. Whereever you studied a lot seems to not have been the right place. Sometimes it helps to just go to the source.

Comment: But where are my manners? Welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for additional help.

Answer (score 16):

### No, they do not.

> ### Using Different Speeds
>
> If you have more than one speed, such as your walking speed and a flying speed, you can switch back and forth between your speeds during your move. Whenever you switch, subtract the distance you've already moved from the new speed. The result determines how much farther you can move. If the result is 0 or less, you can’t use the new speed during the current move.

Winged Boots (and other sources of flight) do not say they add to a flying speed: they give you a flying speed. Winged Boots, for example:

> While you wear these boots, you have a flying speed equal to your walking speed. [...]

As neither the items nor the general movement rules include a provision for adding together multiple sources of a given movement speed, they're just tracked separately.

Answer (score 4):

**It depends on the sources.**

As Shivers pointed out, in your example they do not combine. Instead, you have two different ways to fly: using your wings, and using your magic boots. This is because both sources give you a fly speed.

However, sources that **increase** your speed do combine. For example, Monk class abilities grant "increased movement speed" type effects. The Rogue Scout archetype grants a similar effect. Likewise, Haste multiplies your movement speed. All effects like this, which modify an existing movement speed, do combine.